# jquery autocomplete focus event item undefined

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

So I am building a custom autocomplete box , where an array of local data that looks like this is the data source:

```
{
            label: "joe",
            category: "people"
}
```

I have customised the rendermenu function to enable categories in the menu like so :

```
 $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
        var self = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each(items, function(index, item) {
            if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            self._renderItem(ul, item);
        });
    }
});
```

and I am initialising everything is done by :

```
 $("#search").catcomplete(getConfig(all));
```

where getConfig is :

```
function getConfig(data) {
// autocomplete box configuration for searchbars

return {
    delay: 0,
    source: function (request, response) {
        var prune = request.term,
            arr = prune.split(":");

        if (arr.length > 2) {
            response();
        } else {
            response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(data, arr[arr.length - 1]));
        }
    },
    select: function (e, ui) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addBit(ui.item);
        e.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
    },
    focus: function (e, ui) {
        //console.log(e);
        //e.preventDefault();
        //console.log(ui);
        //$('ul.autocomplete li#floatinput input#search').val(ui.item.category + ":" + ui.item.label);
    },
    position: {
        my: "left top",
        at: "left bottom",
        of: $("ul.autocomplete"),
        collision: "flip flip"
    }
}
}
```

Yet somehow the focus event doesn't have item defined. I tried getting rid of the focus function alltogether , only to get : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined . which means event the default behaviour doesn't work.

Any suggestions welcome!

Here's a fiddle i made to help illustrate > http://jsfiddle.net/ahTCW/3/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `_renderItemData` and not `_renderItem` with jQueryUI >= 1.9:

```
// getconfig
$.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
        var self = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each(items, function(index, item) {
            if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                ul.append("<li style='clear:both'class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            self._renderItemData(ul, item);
        });
    }
});
```

You have another error occurring:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

This one is caused by the option you're passing to the `of` property of the position object. `ul.autocomplete` doesn't exist on the page when the autocomplete widget is instantiated.

**Updated example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kHNS5/

Comment: the position object wouldn't have been a bug in my actual website , i just didn't include all the html in the fiddle. But anyways thanks a lot , i got the answer on irc somewhere as well :D The internet is a nice place!